# Android app crashes when using quantized graph

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have tried to used quantized graph in Android app, the same way as described [here](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/comment-page-1/).
The version of tensorflow used is 0.11.0rc0.

First I ran the following commands:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \
--input=/Users/nikogamulin/Desktop/assets/output_flowers.pb \
--output=/Users/nikogamulin/Desktop/assets/tensorflow_inception_graph_optimized.pb \
--input_names=Mul \
--output_names=final_result

bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph \
--input=/Users/nikogamulin/Desktop/assets/tensorflow_inception_graph_optimized.pb \
--output=/Users/nikogamulin/Desktop/assets/tensorflow_inception_graph_rounded.pb \
--output_node_names=final_result \
--mode=weights_rounded

bazel build //tensorflow/contrib/util:convert_graphdef_memmapped_format
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/util/convert_graphdef_memmapped_format \
--in_graph=/Users/nikogamulin/Desktop/assets/tensorflow_inception_graph_rounded.pb \
--out_graph=/Users/nikogamulin/Desktop/assets/tensorflow_inception_graph_mapped.pb
```

output_flowers.pb is inception v3 graph, which was retrained the same way as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html), except I used different dataset.

When trying to use graph tensorflow_inception_graph_optimized.pb in Android app, everything worked well. Then, after switching to tensorflow_inception_graph_mapped.pb or tensorflow_inception_graph_rounded.pb, the app crashes: as soon as the UI appears, the dialog "Unfortunately, TensorFlow Demo has stopped." pops up.

Below are the beginning lines of TensorFlowImageListener class:

```
  private static final int NUM_CLASSES = 23;
  private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 299;
  private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
  private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128;
  private static final String INPUT_NAME = "Mul:0";
  private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result:0";

  private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/tensorflow_inception_graph_mapped.pb";
  private static final String LABEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/labels_flowers.txt";
...
```

If anyone managed to use quantized inception v3 graph in Android or knows how to solve the problem, I would be very thankful for any suggestions about solving the problem.

Comment: Could you try getting a stack trace and the actual error that gets raised?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into simmilar issue and I think that issue with your steps was that memory mapping part. Because I think this probably output nodes names or something like this.

If you will just strip your model (by optimize_for_inference or even better run strip_unused) and then just quantize it, it will work with inception v3 model correctly - I have just tried it.

However, I would like to do mem mapping part as well, but I have not managed this yet...

EDIT:

Finally I found working solution on Peter Warden's  blog:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \
--input=/tmp/output.pb \
--output=/tmp/optimized.pb \
--input_names=Mul \
--output_names=final_result

bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph \
--input=/tmp/optimized.pb \
--output=/tmp/rounded.pb \
--output_node_names=final_result \
--mode=weights_rounded

bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/util/convert_graphdef_memmapped_format \
--in_graph=/tmp/rounded.pb \
--out_graph=/tmp/mmapped.pb
```

(All scripts have to be build in advance using bazel-bin command before usage).

With this I managed to shrink my v3 retrained model to roundly 21 megs and working in android project. Cheers.